# Run application when start vnc server

Tags: vnc

I want to automatically launch an application when access to the VNC session. The scenario is that when open the VNC session, the application will be run as a popup automatically. I think I need to modify the ~/.vnc/xstartup.turbovnc file, but I don't know where do I need to start.

Thank you.